# how to display all tree child nodes using linq with xml data?

Tags: linq-to-xml

This is my xml file.I want to display all child nodes using linq.can any one give me suggestion or answwer?

Answer (score 0):

This will print out each block and all its fields:

```
var tree = XElement.Parse(text);
foreach(var farm in tree.Descendants("farm"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(farm.Attribute("Name").Value);
    // print the blocks and their fields
    foreach(var block in farm.Descendants("block"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", block.Attribute("Name").Value);
        foreach(var field in block.Descendants("field"))
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0}", field.Attribute("Name").Value);
    }
    // print out the remaining fields that don't belong to a block
    foreach(var field in farm.Descendants("field"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", field.Attribute("Name").Value);
    }
}
```

like so:

```
Farm A
  Field 1
Farm B
  Block North
    Field 11
    Field 12
  Block South
    Field 25
    Field 26
    Field 27
    Field 28
  Field 11
  Field 12
  Field 25
  Field 26
  Field 27
  Field 28
```

Comment: Thank u.but actually my xml file looks like this.how can i display all nodes using linq.<sector Name="Sector Main" Id="1">
    <farm Name="Farm A" >
      <field Name="Field 1"/>
      </farm>
    <farm Name="Farm B" >
      <block Name="Block North" >
        <field Name="Field 11"/>
        <field Name="Field 12"/>
        </block>
      <block Name="Block South">
          <field Name="Field 25"/>
          <field Name="Field 26"/>
          <field Name="Field 27"/>
          <field Name="Field 28"/>
      </block>
    </farm>
  </sector>

Comment: @mihirprasad: Is this better?